# Power BI - How to format missing data in chart, I want to display this blank data in chart

Tags: powerbi

Please see below screenshot. There are values in the table (highlighted in red) that are not reflected in the above chart. How do I get this blank data to display in the chart?

[image: Missing values]

Comment: What I would do is fix it in the data feed. I don't know what your data feed is here so I can't suggest anything. Is it excel? SQL Server?

Comment: repeating a question title in the question as the only description is not really helping us to understand your issue. Use words. Describe your problem. Pretend we cannot see your screen. Explain. Charts can only plot existing data. Maybe you need to create items with 0 as the values to fill in the gaps.

Comment: There was a screenshot that was easy to miss that sheds a lot of light on what the OP is after. I've edited the question.

Comment: You can try writing measure to update blank value as zero by modelling in source and then check it out in visual.

Answer (score 0):

The sr_temperature values that are not appearing on your chart have blank (or missing) values. Blank is generally treated as "no data" rather than 0, so it doesn't get displayed on the chart at all.

If you want those values to display in the chart, you have to either:

1. Add a timestamp record with a value for sr_temperature - if there is no sr_temperature record at all for that timestamp
2. Substitute the blank with the sr_temperature that you want that time to have (such as 0, as @teylyn suggests) - if there is an sr_temperature record for that timestamp already, but the value is BLANK()

How you do that will depend on how the data is being loaded into Power BI (as @Nick.McDermaid says).

Comment: Hi Leonard, thank you for your replay, replace blank valuee with 0 is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Are you going to say what you are looking for?

Comment: as these feature is not added in power bi that display blank value, so this is the answer i am looking for...:)

Comment: A chart displays values. A feature to "display blank value" doesn't make sense in the context of a chart, so to say that the feature "is not added" also doesn't make sense. To plot something on a chart, it needs a value.